# Find the tightest upper bound of $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n v_j^2 w_j \leq C\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n v_j^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, normed-spaces, simplex, geometric-inequalities

Let $w, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with the extra condition $w_j \in (0,1), \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n w_j =1 \thinspace (\dagger)$

I wish to find the tightest upper bound $C$ such that for all $w,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $w$ satisfies condition $\dagger$:

$$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n v_j^2 w_j \leq C\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n v_j^2$$

For example: $w = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5 \\ 0.1 \\ 0.4 \end{bmatrix}$

$$ v_1^2 0.5 + v_2^2 0.1  + v_3^2 0.4  \leq C(v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2)$$

We could take the obvious answer $C =1$, so whatever $w$ I am thrown at $C=1$ always guaranteed to satisfy my inequality. But is there a even tighter bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even take $C = 0.5$ in your example.  In particular, $C = \max_j w_j$ works.  Without additional conditions, I believe this is the tightest upper bound, since it is possible that $w_j = \frac1n$ and $v_i = v_j = v$ for all $i, j$. In this case, $C$ must be at least $\frac1n = \max_j w_j$.

If it has to hold for every $v, w$, then $C = 1$ is the best you can do.  Let $v = (1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and $w = (1-\epsilon, \frac{\epsilon}{n-1}, \frac{\epsilon}{n-1}, \ldots, \frac{\epsilon}{n-1})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.  Sending $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ means we can require $C$ be arbitrarily close to 1.

In particular, suppose $C < 1$ works.  Then take $v = (1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and $w = (\frac{1+C}{2}, \frac{1-C}{2(n-1)},\ldots, \frac{1-C}{2(n-1)})$. It is clear that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} v_j^2 w_j = \frac{1+C}{2} > C = C\sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2$.  This is a contradiction, so $C \ge 1$.  But its obvious that $C = 1$ is a valid option.

Comment: Did my revision help answer your question?

Comment: Yes, although $C$ being "arbitrarily close to 1" is not exactly the most satisfying bound, because we the bound is depending on some infinitestimal number $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: Okay satisfied.

Comment: My point is that if you give me a $C < 1$, I can find you an example $v, w$ that proves it does not work as an upper bound.